# Play framework with Scala and Hadoop doesn't return result to browser

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, playframework

I'm trying to write an API to select data from our Hadoop cluster. I'm using play framework but I'm having some problems. My problem is that I don't get back the result to the browser.

My function:

```
def trends(year:Int  , month:Int  , day:Int ,hour:Int ) =
Action {
var df:org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[String] = null
val data= spark.sql("select * from trends.books")
  .filter(col("year")===year)
  .filter(col("month")===month)
  .filter(col("day")===day)
  .filter(col("query").contains("co.il"))
if(hour != -1)
   df = data.filter(col("hour")===hour).orderBy(desc("ratio")).toJSON
else
   df = data.orderBy(desc("ratio")).toJSON

var final_json=""
df.collect().foreach(final_json+=_.toString()+"\n")
println(final_json)
  println("After print json before ok")
 Ok(final_json)
}
```

the routes file :

```
# Routes
# This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
# ~~~~

# An example controller showing a sample home page
GET     /                           controllers.HomeController.index
# An example controller showing how to use dependency injection
GET     /trends                          controllers.CountController.trends(year:Int,month:Int,day:Int,hour:Int?=-1)
# An example controller showing how to write asynchronous code
GET     /message                    controllers.AsyncController.message

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.versioned(file)
```

Now,I'm trying to return the user all the jsons of all the rows in a specific table filtered by the parameters that the user pass to the function. As you can see I put some prints in the code for debuging. When I run play with sbt.run I get the output but it seems very weird.

The output looks like that :

```
("query":"aa","author":"bb","year":2018,"month":4,"day":10,"hour":20)
("query":"bb","author":"bb","year":2018,"month":4,"day":10,"hour":20)
("query":"cc","author":"bb","year":2018,"month":4,"day":10,"hour":20)
After print json before ok
```

Now because Chrome doesn't get any result back it refreshes the pages and then again:

```
("query":"aa","author":"bb","year":2018,"month":4,"day":10,"hour":20)
("query":"bb","author":"bb","year":2018,"month":4,"day":10,"hour":20)
("query":"cc","author":"bb","year":2018,"month":4,"day":10,"hour":20)
After print json before ok
```

and again..

```
("query":"aa","author":"bb","year":2018,"month":4,"day":10,"hour":20)
("query":"bb","author":"bb","year":2018,"month":4,"day":10,"hour":20)
("query":"cc","author":"bb","year":2018,"month":4,"day":10,"hour":20)
After print json before ok

and so on..
```

Why don't I get anything back ?

Answer (score 1):

I once ran through the similar issue. Making it asynchronous fixed the issue for me.

Comment: What do you mean by asynchronous ?

Comment: Something that does not block the current thread.https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaAsync

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the browser keep refreshing itself and therefore I got this recursive loop. I used the curl in cmd and it worked.